# How to boot Raspberry pi 3 without sd card

Tags: pi-3, boot, sd-card, pi-3b+

I have lost my micro sd card and am unable to use my raspberry pi 3B. I can't buy a new one since online delivery has been stopped where I live due to the lockdown. Is it possible to boot my raspberry pi using a USB pen drive or another sd card(That one is big, it is not a micro sd card and it is just 2 gb). I also have a micro-sd card reader in case that is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what use would a micro-sd card reader without a card to stick into it?

Comment: You've checked your mobiles and cameras for any hidden micro SD?

Comment: Check this link please https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Comment: @SohanArafat - how does that help? you need to boot into a functional system to enable that

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is unclear - do you have a Pi3B or a Pi3b+?

The Pi3b+ can be booted from USB.
The Pi3b can be booted from USB only after it is enabled (which requires SD Card).

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Comment: How do I know which model I have? Mine says "Raspberry Pi 3 model B V1.2 "

Comment: 3B+ has metal cap on the wifi and the CPU - https://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Raspberry-Pi-3B-top_1500.jpg - and says `Pi 3 Model B+` on the board

Comment: So, I have a raspberry pi 3 B and I still need an sd card for that, then there is no point in doing all this

Comment: @AmayAgarwal Please re-read Milliways' answer carefully: you only need an SD card  to *enable* USB boot

Comment: I know but I dont have a card at all let alone use it only once to enable USB boot

Comment: Link is stale... do you have a direct/up-to-date link?